# getting error while relating a foreign key to save form in django

Tags: django, django-forms

**models.py**

```
class OtherData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    otherdata = models.ForeignKey(OtherData)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images/')
```

I am looking for saving an image on an instance of otherdata, getting integrity error `NOT NULL constraint failed`. I am using a model form to save data. I tried to use form valid method as follows in **views.py** but still the same error.

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = self.request.user
    instance.otherdata_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    return super(ImageCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Looking forward for a help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this,you can get **OtherData instance** from pk

```
def form_valid(self, form):
     instance = form.save(commit=False)
     instance.user = self.request.user
     instance.otherdata = OtherData.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
     return super(ImageCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and also small changes in model.py

```
class OtherData(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='other_data')

class ProductImage(models.Model):
     otherdata = models.ForeignKey(OtherData)
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='product_image')
     image = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='images/')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After making the changes as you suggested, new error is 'DoesNotExist at /image/add/
OtherData matching query does not exist.'

Comment: Check your pk value not exist in otherimage instance

Comment: i tried to print OtherData.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')), but not getting any output

Comment: can you print self.kwargs.get('pk') this one

Comment: its output is none